# Redirect URLs to other domain with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I am getting rid of my blog on my main site and want to direct everybody to my other domain where I will continue. I have already cross posted my most popular articles, but I want people to be directed there automatically.

How can I use .htaccess to redirect specific URLs to the new URLs?

IE
http://domain.com/blog/2015/jan/responsive-doesn-t-mean-mobile-first

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch to redirect your rule to a new location .

Try in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch ^/blog/2015/jan/responsive-doesn-t-mean-mobile-first$ http://newdomain.com
```

Comment: OK, I feel a little stupid as I forgot the new URL structure also changed and I didn't include that...

Would I do this:

    RedirectMatch ^/blog/2015/jan/responsive-doesn-t-mean-mobile-first$ http://newdomain.com/new/url-structure

Comment: Worked with the new URL structure as above. Does this do 301?

Comment: this does 302 by default , you can add status code 301 to it 

**RedirectMatch 301 ^/pattern**

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the followup.